# Apply discounts on subscriptions with PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am using the PayPal API for subscription, so far on Sandbox and everything works as expected. I have read the whole documentation of [PayPal api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/) and unfortunately couldn't find what I need, that's why I'm asking here.

I am recently considering to add Discounts as well, and wish to have that in two ways:

- New customer enters the discount code the first time they want to join the company. *(e.g. use the Valentines Discount Code and get 10€ on your first month).*
- Already existing customers get a discount on one of the months. (Let's say they pay 25€ monthly, and they get a 10€ discount in the 3rd month for whatever reason, now the payments look something like this. 25€ 25€ **15€** 25€ etc...).

Is there really no way to add discounts to subscriptions in PayPal? I would be really glad for any hints / help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For discounts at checkout time, when creating the subscription and specifying a `plan_id`, you can also specify a `plan` object with different billing cycle values that override it, for example a lower regular amount or an additional lower amount trial period. See the [Create Subscription](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions-create-request-body) API call; available parameters for the createSubscription JS SDK function are the same.

For discounts after a subscription is active, you will need to update the subscription. This can be done with the [Update Subscription](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_patch) patch API call.